# How can I print an input prompt in python on its own line when ran using popen or run in the subprocess library?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I've created the following example to illustrate my question:

Let's say student_file.py is:

```py
curr_year = int(input("Enter year: "))
print(f"Next year is {curr_year + 1}")
```

So when running the program, the output in the terminal is like:

```
Enter year: 4323
Next year is 4324
```

In my case, I'm running another program that uses multiple inputs using this student file, so the desired output looks like:

```
Enter year: 
Next year is 3234
Enter year: 
Next year is 3112
Enter year: 
Next year is 1322
Enter year: 
Next year is 2222
```

However, with the current code snippet in, for example, temp.py:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
year_list = ['3233\n', '3111\n', '1321\n', '2221']
for year in year_list:
    p = Popen(["python3", "student_file.py"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, encoding="ascii")
    output = p.communicate(input=year)[0]
    print(output, end="")
```

The output is currently:

```py
Enter year: Next year is 3234
Enter year: Next year is 3112
Enter year: Next year is 1322
Enter year: Next year is 2222
```

Because I'm testing other files, I don't want to change student_file.py at all, and only want to modify test.py. Is this possible at all? I'm fine with using any method to accomplish this, whether it be popen, run, or something else as long as it accomplishes this desired output.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little Workaround :)

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
year_list = ['3233\n', '3111\n', '1321\n', '2221']
for year in year_list:
    p = Popen(["python3", "student_file.py"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, encoding="ascii")
    output = p.communicate(input=year)[0]
    print(output.replace(": ",": \n"), end="")
```

Using Pexpect

```py
import pexpect
year_list = ['3233', '3111', '1321', '2221']
for year in year_list:
    child = pexpect.spawn("python student_file.py")

    child.sendline(year)
    lines = [i.decode('utf-8').rstrip() for i in child.readlines()]
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
``
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) The only thing I'm nervous about is I'd like this to make a general script where the input prompt could be different and so it doesn't necessarily include a :, and I'd be nervous in case a program could use a : in it's output somewhere

Comment: Works great! Really appreciate it.